# Создать баш команду

Tags: bash

Подскажите или скиньте ссылку как создавать команды.

К примеру хочу написать команду createLiveReload ./ . где createLiveReload команда, а ./ переменная.

Алгоритм выполнения этой команды, создать файлик text.txt в который записать текст 'какой то текст' переменная из терминала 'еще какой то текст'

Спасибо

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html

Comment: http://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/bash_scripting_guide/

Comment: `#!/bin/bash\necho "какой-то текст $1 еще какой-то текст" > file.out`

Comment: http://rus-linux.net/nlib.php?name=/MyLDP/BOOKS/Bash-Guide-1.12-ru/bash-guide-00.html. Это первые 3 ссылки из гугла (`bash manual`)

Comment: @andy.37 1  а потом добавить alias command = путь к баш скрипту ?

Comment: как один из вариантов.

Answer (score 1):

например, вот так можно создать:

```
$ function createLiveReload() { echo "какой то текст$1еще какой то текст" > text.txt; }
```

вот так можно выполнить:

```
$ createLiveReload ./
```

а вот что получится в файле `text.txt` из текущего каталога:

```
$ cat text.txt 
какой то текст./еще какой то текст
```